# Android: best way to upload/download number of files in background

Tags: android, ios, asihttprequest

I have recently developed an iPhone application which involves media (Images, Audio and video) sync. operation with my web server.

I have used `ASIHTTPRequest` in my iOS application for simultaneous uploading and downloading and do some work in every request finished and failed methods as  `ASIHTTPRequest` provides these methods.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

Is there any similar library for android. That allow me to `upload/download` in queue and update me after every successful or failure of request?

Comment: this is the best library of ios

Comment: @DixitPatel I need library for Android not for iOS

Answer (score 1):

For downloads part, [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) can be useful . Alas!, no such thing for uploads (yet). To have IOS like functionality, you'd need to write a custom background service.

Comment: Its strange, there is no library for both operations so far

Comment: @IrfanDANISH I too wonder, given its all java, the popularity, and n number of frameworks around, no one had yet extended API in meaningful ways. But I see an interesting library project.

Comment: @IrfanDANISH just thinking of writing one.

Answer (score 1):

In android you can use the Download Manager.
Here is [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Internet/Download)
or you can use the asynchronous class
Please refer the below link

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)